# mysql insert into select join - copy values from one column to another table, passing through a connecting table

Tags: mysql, join, select

I can't get this to work

```
CREATE TABLE `oc_tax_class` (
  `tax_class_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `oc_tax_rate`
--

CREATE TABLE `oc_tax_rate` (
  `tax_rate_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `geo_zone_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `rate` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0000,
  `type` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `oc_tax_rule`
--

CREATE TABLE `oc_tax_rule` (
  `tax_rule_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tax_class_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tax_rate_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `based` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `priority` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

3 tables. I want `oc_tax_class.title = oc_tax_rate.name`
I believe, although I'm not sure, that I should

```
INSERT INTO oc_tax_class(title)
```

or

```
UPDATE oc_tax_class SET title = ...

SELECT oc_tax_rate.name, oc_tax_rule.tax_class_id
JOIN oc_tax_rule ON oc_tax_rate.tax_rate_id = oc_tax_rule.tax_rate_id
```

And then I don't know what to do next.
I need to copy values from one column to another table, passing through a connecting table.

Comment: Why, *why* are you using MyISAM in 2022? Use InnoDB. There's really no excuse to use that obsolete engine.

Comment: storing values multiple times is not good db design

Comment: These tables are also missing a `PRIMARY KEY`. In most cases that should be `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: I'm with Jens here. Why can't you reference the other table, as one does in a relational database, instead of force-copying values and denormalizing your data?

Comment: Can't put all the code in here with auto increment and everything because then I have too much code and too little explanations. And not my server so it stays MyISAM

Comment: Read about update .. join ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL supports a multi-table UPDATE syntax, but the documentation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/update.html) has pretty sparse examples of it.

In your case, this may work:

```
UPDATE oc_tax_class 
JOIN oc_tax_rule USING (tax_class_id)
JOIN oc_tax_rate USING (tax_rate_id)
SET oc_tax_class.title = oc_tax_rate.name;
```

I did not test this. I suggest you test it first on a sample of your data, to make sure it works the way you want it to.

Comment: It works thank you. @Jens above said this was what I was looking for and it looks so simple. Thanks again

Comment: Yes, it's a pity that the manual describes it in such an unclear way. It's a very useful feature.